# Python GUI, Label text showing "{}" instead of Space

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing the code as mentioned below to display Table of 2. There must be "Space" shown Before & After "X" as " X " but instead I'm getting "{}". Seeking for Help as I'm new to programming.

Code:

```
    import tkinter
    table = tkinter.Tk()
    table.geometry("280x420") 
    table.title("GUI Table Practice") 
    n = 2
    for i in range(1, 11):
        v = (n, ' X ', i, ' = ', n*i)
        s = tkinter.Label(text=v, font="Times 20")
        s.pack()
 
    table.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting instead of passing a tuple as text:

```
import tkinter

table = tkinter.Tk()
table.geometry("280x420")
table.title("GUI Table Practice")
n = 2
for i in range(1, 11):
    s = tkinter.Label(text=f'{n} X {i} = {n*i}', font="Times 20")
    s.pack()

table.mainloop()
```